# QGIS modeler and pyqgs standalone programming questions

Tags: python, pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-processing

i have create two model in QGIS modeler one path for raster and one for vector and now i want to create a QGIS plugin from that models but i have some questions.

first model :

[image: first model]
that model work fine in QGIS from processing tools but now work on standalone pyqgis script because i thing i have only the final exports(i thing) from aglorithms but that i need only the final.

if i change the model to :

[image: second modele]

with exports for any algorithms then working but i dont like this method because  keep not necesery layers for my task i need keep only the final export.

how to fix that ?

here the python codes :

model 1 :

```
##=name
##myvector=vector
##newvector=output vector
outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', myvector,'mynewfield',0,10.0,3.0,True,'a+b',None)
outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_2=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'mynew2_field',0,10.0,3.0,True,'a+b+c',newvector)
```

raster :

```
##test=name
##myraster=raster
##final=output raster
outputs_grass7:r.slope_1=processing.run('grass7:r.slope', myraster,0,False,'1.0','0.0',None,'0.0',None)
outputs_qgis:rastercalculator_1=processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', [outputs_GRASS7R.SLOPE_1['slope']],'GRASS7R.SLOPE_1:slope@1*100','0.0',None,None)
outputs_qgis:rastercalculator_1=processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', [outputs_QGISRASTERCALCULATOR_1['OUTPUT']],'QGISRASTERCALCULATOR_1:OUTPUT@1*50','0.0',None,final)
```

model 2 :

```
##=name
##myvector=vector
##output=output vector
##newvector=output vector
outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', myvector,'mynewfield',0,10.0,3.0,True,'a+b',output)
outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_2=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'mynew2_field',0,10.0,3.0,True,'a+b+c',newvector)
```

raster :

```
##test=name
##myraster=raster
##slope=output raster
##outraster=output raster
##final=output raster
outputs_grass7:r.slope_1=processing.run('grass7:r.slope', myraster,0,False,'1.0','0.0',None,'0.0',slope)
outputs_qgis:rastercalculator_1=processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', [outputs_GRASS7R.SLOPE_1['slope']],'GRASS7R.SLOPE_1:slope@1*100','0.0',None,outraster)
outputs_qgis:rastercalculator_1=processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', [outputs_QGISRASTERCALCULATOR_1['OUTPUT']],'QGISRASTERCALCULATOR_1:OUTPUT@1*50','0.0',None,final)
```

how to do model 1 to work ?what is the difference ?

Comment: What errors do you receive when you run model 1?

Comment: @Joseph `outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_2` cant take output from `outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1`

Comment: Which QGIS version and platform are you using? I can confirm that your model 1 code works for QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit.

Comment: @joseph I use QGIS 2.18.7 64 bit windows 10 64 bit python 2.7 32bit

Comment: Don't have Windows 10 to test this so hopefully others can advise :)

Comment: @Joseph I need to change my wondows version?

Comment: Oh no no, I'm not saying that! Windows 10 might not even be the problem, perhaps it could be your specific QGIS 2.18.7 version... I'm hoping someone who has the same specs as you could also test your code and report back. Because for me, your code works perfectly fine.